# Creating AddIns for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: add-in, arcgis-pro

How can I create an AddIn to ArcGIS Pro and where can I find it from ArcGIS Pro application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ArcGIS Pro currently does not support Python add-ins. There were [no plans for a Python Add-in support](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/117238) in ArcGIS Pro. ArcGIS Pro has arcpy site package shipped though (you can author Python script tools).

Your only option is [ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-samples-beta) which is going to be released soon (it is in beta now).

**UPDATE: from [Esri Forum](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/119963)**

> ArcGIS Pro will feature a new .Net API using coarse grained objects
>   which we currently (and internally) calling ProObjects. Add-Ins based
>   on the ArcObjects APIs will not work in Pro. Think of the architecture
>   difference of ArcMap and Pro being somewhat related when you make a
>   comparison between ArcGIS Engine and the ArcGIS Runtime.
>
> Getting an add-in into Pro is similar to getting an add-in into
>   ArcMap. The backstage in Pro is featuring an Add-In Manager that works
>   in a similar way to the classic desktop applications.

Comment: Not having Python ADD-IN capability for ArcGIS pro is a step backward - sad deal. I hope ESRI realizes the power of Python Add-ins and not having to resort to using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As an update, ESRI appears to be have this idea under considered per this forum thread: https://community.esri.com/ideas/10509-python-add-ins-for-arcgis-pro